# using overlay to highlight or mark text block areas

Tags: java, android, ocr, overlay, google-mlkit

I am using google ml kit vision in android studio and I have made an ocr app.how can I use overlay to mark detected character or text area in the image handled to text recognizer?

here is the extractTextfromImage method implementation code in *java*:

```
    private void extractTextFromImage() {


        // Convert the image to an InputImage
        InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(ImageUnit.drawableToBitmap(imagePreview.getDrawable()),0);


        TextRecognizer recognizer =
                TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);


        // Process the image for text recognition
        recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Text visionText) {
                        // Run UI-related operations on the UI thread
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Extract text from the result
                                //String extractedText = visionText.getText();
                                extractedText=visionText.getText();

                                // Do something with the extracted text
                                // For example, display it in a TextView
                                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.extracted);
                                textView.setText(extractedText);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Run UI-related operations on the UI thread
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Handle any errors that occurred during text recognition
                                Toast.makeText(ImagePreviewActivity.this, "Text recognition failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

I saw some articles and documents that are confusing. some use a layoutsource file for using overlay some use drawable resources and some aren't using them. what is the most effecient way?

Comment: Check out these two pages: android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/GraphicOverlay.java. https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/transform-output